# Why time complexity of union-find is $O(lgN)$ with only "Union by Rank"?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, union-find

I'm studying time complexity of Union-Find data structure.

I saw time complexity of union and find function depends on some conditions.

1. without anything: $O(N)$
2. with Union by Rank: $O(\log N)$
3. with Path Compression: $O(\alpha(N))$ which is inverse Ackermann function.

I understood $O(N)$ because of skewed tree of disjoint set. But, I cannot understand $O(\log N)$. I looked on Wikipedia and Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find it. How can I prove second time complexity?

Comment: Here is a Wikipedia link that directly deals with your problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#by_rank

Comment: refer Tim roughgarden's coursera data structures videos for it. He has the best explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, here is the precise statement of the case 2 in OP's question.

> A sequence of m MAKE-SET, UNION, and FIND operations, n of which are MAKE-SET operations, can be performed on a disjoint-set forest with union by rank in worst-case time $O(m\log_2 n)$.

In fact, it is trivial to see that the MAKE-SET and UNION operations run in $O(1)$ time. So the question is really about the time-complexity of the FIND operation.

Here are the properties of the disjoint-set forest you can prove.

1. Given any node $u$ that has been added to the set of union-find data structure, the ranks of the nodes in a path from $u$ to its root is strictly increasing.
2. A node $u$ which is root of a sub-tree with rank $r$ has at least $2^r$ nodes. (This fact can be proved by induction on $r$).
3. Every node has rank at most $\log_2 n$.

With properties 1 and 3, it should be easy to prove the desired time complexity.

The above explanation follows roughly the section 21.4 in *Introduction To Algorithms*, third edition by CLRS. Readers are encouraged to read the chapter 21 of that book.